# What causes a hydraulic jump in flowing water?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I understand that when water flowing at a faster velocity enters an area where it's flowing at a slower velocity, a [hydraulic jump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydraulic_jump) occurs. What exactly is responsible for this sudden change? Are there certain variables of the water flow that contribute to the properties of the hydraulic jump such as the jump's height?

Comment: Duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/127470/