# Water falling on a surface

Tags: fluid-dynamics

When water falls on a solid surface, a circle is made by it. It is different from ripples because ripples do not end in a certain radius, but when you see this circle, it has a certain boundary. Why does this happen? Can we calculate the radius?

Comment: What you're describing is known as a [hydraulic jump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydraulic_jump), which is not addressed in the proposed duplicate. I don't know enough about the phenomenon to give an answer on the radius, though.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/127470/2451 , http://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/5490/2588

Answer (score 2):

There are several phenomena that could fit the description in your question, but like suggested @emilio-pisanty and @qmechanic, you're certainly talking about the **hydraulic jump**!

The answer to your question is in fact quite complex since it hadn't been qualitatively addressed until 1993!  T. Bohr, P. Dimon and V. Putkaradge, J. Fluid Mech. **254** 635(1993), available [here](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-fluid-mechanics/article/div-classtitleshallow-water-approach-to-the-circular-hydraulic-jumpdiv/575ACF777C7217B55BBAD4FAF33589E9#), showed the radius should scale as $R_j \propto Q^{5/8}\nu^{-3/8}g^{-1/8}$, where $Q$ is the volume flux, $\nu$ is the kinematic viscosity and $g$ is the gravitational acceleration. A. Mukherjee, A. Datta and J. K. Bhattacharjee confirmed this scaling in an other paper in 2002, available [here](http://cds.cern.ch/record/577484/files/0208079.pdf).

Your question could also refer to **drop impacts**. When a drop of fluid falls on a hydrophobic surface, a bead is formed at the periphery of the impacting drop. This deformation was studied in C. Clanet, C. Béguin, D. Richard and D. Quéré, J. Fluid Mech. **517** 199(2004), available [here](https://www.pmmh.espci.fr/~jbico/TP/clanet04.pdf), wherein a scaling of the maximal spreading is proposed.

Comment: Depending on the viscosity (and possibly the volume flux; I'm not sure), the boundary of a hydraulic jump doesn't even have to be circular, but may also be e.g. pentagonal!

Comment: I would have thought that if the problem is axisymmetric and the surface is ideal and isotropic then the hydraulic jump is circular. Under which conditions does a pentagonal jump can be observed?

Comment: The viscosity has to be ~10x that of water. You can have up to 14-sided polygons, I think. Some friends of mine experimented with this in 2002 (together with Tomas Bohr, whos paper you link to). It's pretty contraintuitive. Their project is [here](rudar.ruc.dk/bitstream/1800/7246/1/main.pdf), but is in Danish. But have a look at [Martens+ 12](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.4599). Or [image-google polygonal hydraulic jump](https://www.google.dk/search?q=polygonal+hydraulic+jump&biw=1313&bih=874&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjFpNycsa3SAhWJfywKHWKvDNsQ_AUIBigB). :)

Comment: Oops, wrong link to the Danish text. The correct is [here](http://milne.ruc.dk/imfufatekster/pdf/411.pdf) (but is still in Danish, so it doesn't really matter, I guess).